# Dismiss popover from the button on popup

Tags: ios, ios5

I have created a popover, containing a table 
when user will select the row at that time I want to dismiss popover. 
any Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html)... Have a look at the popoverclass...

Answer (score 0):

When your table delegate method gets called, close the popover:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

     // Handle the row click
}
```

Where *popoverController* is an instance variable set up when you created the popover.